# Reroute subdomain calls to different ports/webservers (Reverse proxy)

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, domain

I don't know if this is the right place for this question but:

I currently have a webserver on my ubuntu server that can be accessed by port 80. Also I have another webserver running at port 6969.

I also have a domain name that is pointet to my server.

Is it possible to somehow reroute a sub domain like "service.mydomain.com" to the webserver running on port 6969 without writing the port to the end of the url?

And I don't mean to just host one webserver and if a subdomain is called to just serve differend html files or something. One webserver is hosted via another software so I can't just merge it into another webserver.

Comment: Yes, this is called a reverse proxy setup. There are lots of guides on how to configure this. However, you need to tell us what webserver you are using so we can give more detailed instructions/find better duplicates. Add this in the question by editing it, not in the comments.

Comment: You are right. I found this question and that is exactly what I want to do:  [https://serverfault.com/questions/753105/how-to-reverse-proxy-to-different-places-depending-on-subdomain-in-nginx](how-to-reverse-proxy-to-different-places-depending-on-subdomain-in-nginx) .

For the webserver I am using: what server to use for the reverse proxy doesn't matter. I prefer the easier one

Answer (score 1):

After I got told by Panki what this is called what I need I directly found a tutorial for that with nginx:

1. Install nginx

   ```
   sudo apt install nginx nginx-extras
   ```
2. Unlink the default page

   ```
   sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
   ```
3. Create the reversed proxy configuration

   ```
   cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
   sudo nano reverse-proxy.conf
   ```
4. Writing the config

   ```
   server {
           server_name sub1.mydomain.com;
           location / {
                   proxy_pass      http://mydomain.com:6969;
           }
   }
   server {
           server_name sub2.mydomain.com;
           location / {
                   proxy_pass      http://mydomain.com:81;
           }
   }
   ```
5. Save and reload nginx

   ```
   sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/reverse-proxy.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/reverse-proxy.conf
   sudo nginx -s reload
   ```